# How can I use a config file in AngularJS app to provide data to script in index.html?

Tags: angularjs

In my index.html file, I have a script that needs some variables set from an external config.properties file. This file simply contains a JSON object:

```
{
    "appUrl": "http://myappurl.com",
    "appId": "10"
}
```

Inside my index.html file, I'd like to do something like:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
   <head>
       <script>
          // adds script element with appUrl as a source
         var url = "{{appUrl}}";
         new_script_element.src= url + "myApp.js";
       </script>
    </head>
 </head>
```

How do I read in the properties file, convert values to constants, and pass the constants to the controller for use? Please be specific about what files should be created/modified, ie: app.js (where "MyApp" module is defined), index.html, and myController.js. It may also help to know that in app.js my current myApp.config looks like this:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {...}
```

Comment: Not sure what the use-case is, but you can't have `ng-app="myApp"` on the HTML node and inside that define what the URL for `myApp.js` should be. At that time, myApp should already be running or Angular will throw errors. For the rest, just create a static config.json file and read it via [$http](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2612-using-the-http-service-in-angularjs-to-make-ajax-requests.htm)

Comment: Do you use a build tool? If possible I think its better to assign the app specific data during build time rather than runtime. This can be done in various ways using browserify, grunt, gulp etc.

Comment: I'm actually adding a <script> element with a src to another totally separate application, piwik,js, not myApp.js. Piwik is like Google analytics and you need to specify the piwik url and site ID. See the block of code I need to add to the head [here](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics/blob/master/samples/piwik.html)